# JQuery-DataTables First Click on row doesn't show

Tags: jquery

I'm using Data Tables in my system and I just upgraded from Legacy versions to the last 1.10.18 and I'm currently using extension "Select".

My problem is that I cant listen to the first click in a row properly. I want to active certain buttons when a Row is selected, but it doesn't happen until the second click. Do you have any idea what could it be?

**JQuery Java-Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var table = $('#SitesTable').DataTable({
    select: true,
  });

  $('#SitesTable').on('click', null, function (event) {
    console.log(table.rows({ selected: true }).count());
    console.log(table.rows({ selected: true }).any());
  });
```

[This is what consoles writes in the first three cicks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYpiA.png)

Answer (score 0):

It appears your listening on the table and not on the row for the click.  Modify your event to listen on the table row instead

```
 $('#SitesTable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function (event) {
    console.log(table.rows({ selected: true }).count());
    console.log(table.rows({ selected: true }).any());
  });
```

Comment: is the event firing at all?  Possibly the SiteTable is not yet in the dom when this is running?